# JSON If Confirm message ok , session clear than return to MainPage

Tags: json, model-view-controller, get

,Hi all,

I have a href for exit

```
<a href="Home/Exit" id="exit-link">Exit</a>
```

I am trying to show Confirm Message on click to a href.

İf confirm is ok I need to go **Home/Exit session out** than show **Index(MainPage)**

However,
Confirm does not work , also ı can get Index Page but ı only see Index as **HTML(lots of texts)**

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#exit-link").on("click", function () {
if (confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?")) {
$.ajax({
url: "/Home/Exit",
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
contentType: 'application/json',
success: function (mydata) {
$("#Page").html(mydata);
},
error: function () {
$("#Page").html("Fail");
}
});
return false;
}
});
});
```

```
<div id="Page"></div>
```

My Exit ActionResult

```
public ActionResult Exit(MyModel model)
{
int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["KullaniciId"]); // User Id
if (UserId >= 1)
{
Session.Clear();
}
var stringView = RenderRazorViewToString("Index", model);
return Json(stringView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function showmypopup() {
        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to exit?")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/Exit",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function (mydata) {
                    $("#Page").html(mydata);
                },
                error: function () {
                    $("#Page").html("Fail");
                }
            });

        }else
            return false;
    }
```

And you should  make a call from your link

a href="#" id="exit-link" onclick="showmypopup()">Exit